# Jekyll --force_polling not automatically refreshing (vagrant machine)

Tags: vagrant, jekyll, reload, polling, watch

I am using a vagrant machine, I have installed Jekyll and I am having trouble getting Jekyll to watch the files and refresh them, after search around I found that I needed to use the `--force_polling` tag which now means if I refresh the files are updated but watch does still not refresh the browser.

I can see the files being updated in my terminal window.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jekyll `watch` will generate your static files when you make change to sources. It is not supposed to reload page in your browser.

In order to do this, you can try to use **livereload**. Take a look at [Daniel Doezema blog for setup instructions](http://dan.doezema.com/2014/01/setting-up-livereload-with-jekyll/)